# How irritating is a biology education researcher in MESE?

Tags: discussion, vision

First, props to you all for creating the first STEM education SE community. It's a great site with great questions.

Second, how does the community feel about less-pure (in the [xkcd sense](http://xkcd.com/435/)) biology visitors? I am a full-time biology education researcher and biology lecturer. 
I'm pretty good at STEM education literature and teaching experience, but I've got no math to speak of.

Do you feel it's appropriate for biology (or physics or chemistry) people to participate? I've felt like I have useful things to say regarding general pedagogy, like clickers or flipped classrooms or exam analysis. And I'm smart enough (I hope) to stay out of the way when math is being discussed. But if you'd rather stick to math expert contributors, I can remain over in Academia SE.

Comment: Especially while we're in this new stage, I say: the more the merrier. In general, I think it's better to offer contributions and see whether they fit the ideal mold of the site, based on voting, rather than withhold contributions for fear of irritating the users here.

Comment: Considering that your answers have a lot of up votes, and the one down vote came on a question where someone down voted half the answers, I think you're doing fine.

Comment: By the way, I'd like to hear your thoughts on this question: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1164/what-are-some-activities-projects-i-can-assign-to-calculus-students-from-bio-che

Comment: @BrianRushton, I'm afraid I have nothing helpful to offer you there -- I've never worked with a mathematician to design good projects, and current biology coursework has little calculus problem-solving. I'm happy to do a bit of exploring in published research, if you like. But I haven't *used* anything.

Answer (score 14):

Yes.

As brendansullivan07 says in his comment, you (and, more generally, representatives of other disciplines) are and should be welcome on this site.

The *topic* of this site is about the teaching of mathematics. But this does not mean that teachers of other disciplines cannot contribute valuable insights to the questions, and even make us aware of some aspects we cannot observe in the mathematics classroom.

So please, do continue to share your valuable insights.

Answer (score 9):

I would certainly welcome the participation of researchers in biology and biology education, as long as the discussion remains on-topic.

Indeed, I have written a question on the relation between biology and calculus that I would love to get an answer to:

[How is calculus helpful for biology majors?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/how-is-calculus-helpful-for-biology-majors)